# Navigation to Non-Navigation Directions?

Tags: navigation

I recently came across very detailed intructions (like 18 pages) of how to convert a GX 470 from Navigation to Non-navigation... it was a game changer! But, egads, now I can't find them! Any help??

Comment: Can you add more details?  For example, what is a GX470?  What do you mean by Non-navigation, do you mean remove the SATNAV?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.